# KVM's Virt-Manager is not able to PXE boot KVM machines from MAAS Server

Tags: networking, juju, maas, kvm-virtualization

I am using virt manager for deploying maas on kvm and other maas nodes for openstack cloud and juju controller running on those KVMs in a dediated single server. For that purpose i have made 2 networks one is br0 attached with eth0 (physical interface) for maas public access and other is "isolated private network" for maas nodes. i have attached my maas-server running on one of the kvm with these two networks by making 2 interfaces (i.e public and private). Now i am trying to PXE boot juju controller machine from MAAS private network but it does not pxe boot that machine and instead giving an error "No bootable device".  Why this is happening? MAAS is supposed to builtin provide a dhcp and tftp server but juju controller is not able to pxe boot fom MAAS server.. Do i need to configure my network ?? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

maas server can not be deployed on dual interface .

you must deploy 2 instancesof maas :

- a maas api   server
- a maas rackd controller , it will provide dhcp,pxe,and proxy api call .

And you must deploy maas 2.5 .

The simple setup is too have only one network interface  by maas server .

Comment: You mean 2 instances on 2 KVMs with a single interface (or it can be dual i.e public or private)??